# Working click event in current index with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, click, indexof

I have code below in HTML

```html
<ul>
   <li>Item1</li>
   <li>Item2</li>
   <li>Item3</li>
   <li>Item4</li>
   <li>Item5</li>
   <li>Item6</li>
   <li>Item7</li>
   <li>Item8</li>
</ul>
```

i want write one code for all "li" tag in click event!

i can get index width this code

```js
$("li").click(function () {
  var current = $(this).parent().children().index();
}
```

but i can't do any thing with them for example:
i want change current index color or add any CSS code!

what can i do!

thanks for spend Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want when click one `li`, then change its color(or other style), try `css`:

```
$("li").click(function () {
  $(this).css({
    "width": 50px,
    "background-color": "red"
    // maybe other attribute pairs
  });
}
```

API guide: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Change class is also a good way:

```
$("li").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("new-color-new-width-li");
}
```

Please check `addClass`, `removeClass`, `toggleClass` for more details:
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: this code run for all "li" tag 

in jquery code first i get back to parent which is "ui" then get all children of it which is "li". !!!

in this part with "index" i can get each position of "li" like "0" , "1",...,"7".

but i can't do any thing more! 

i want change current index when i click it! like change color or run the other one CSS cod.

Comment: @HosseinMarzban ``$(this)`` means the ``li`` you clicked, not all ``li`` tag. I don't think it is necessary to get ``li`` index, just use ``$(this)`` you can get the ``li`` you clicked.

Comment: easier to change a class instead of having to undo inline css for next click